# Parse Swift: User relations with a "friends request"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, relationship

I am kind of new to programming and parse, but I am really interested in it. 
I already know how to create a PFUser and how to set relations between Users, thanks to the tutorial provided on parse.com. The thing is they only have examples for one User following another User. I would prefer sending like a "Friends Request", for example like in instagram if a profile is not open to anybody. 
How can I code that? What do I need to think of? 
Example Code is very welcome :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely create a FriendRequest table as @MatthewLuiHK suggested. However, I don't know if this is the best way to track who is following who, this would just allow for tracking open friend requests. In my apps I use a cloud code function to set a `friends` array in each user's object, as you cannot modify other users without the master key. Below is the function I use:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("handleFriendRequest", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    //console.log(request.user);
    query.get(request.params.fromUserId).then(function(fromUser) {

        console.log("Hello World!");
        fromUser.addUnique("friends", request.user);
        return fromUser.save();

    }).then(function(savedFromUser) {

        response.success("Successfully made a new friend! :)");

    }, function(error) {

        response.error("Error occurred: " + error.message);

    });


});
```

Before calling this function, you need to add the `fromUser` pointer to the array in the current users `friends` column, then send in the fromUser `objectId` into this function under the "fromUserId" key in the dictionary.

Comment: So did I get that right, this function is just handling the requests in the table? But how can I tell UserB that UserA send a request? And how can I save it when UserB accepted it? I know this is a lot I am asking for, maybe you know some homepage or any source where I can find help?! Like a tutorial

Comment: Hi, yes, that is correct. What you will want to do is create a FriendRequest table with fromUser and toUser columns. You can create one of these objects when someone sends a friend request. When you want to show a user the requests they have in their "inbox" you can execute a query that will show all objects where they are the toUser.

Comment: okay, perfect! Thanks a lot for your help! One more question :D What do I have to do when UserB accepts the request?? just deleting the request and setting a "real" relationship between both users? Like I said, if you know any good source where I can learn about that topic, let me know :)

Comment: I do not know any tutorials on the topic, but when userB accepts the request you would call the Cloud Code function I posted above (you can read about CC in the parse.com docs), and you would delete the FriendRequest object. Please up vote my answer if I helped you! :)

Comment: Sorry that I missed the "Friend request" part. To me, the "Friend request" mechanism can be solved by adding with a "confirmed" property on the "FollowClass" and a push notification. If you currently want it to be a bidirectional relationship, add another "Follow" when toUser has confirmed the request. The good side of taking a relationship out of the user class is you don't have to parse through every user to get their following status(more graph). For someone concern the privacy, use privacy control. Also some day you may want a pure "following" relationship like Facebook page does ^^

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively simple.

For register or signin, call the PFUser's class method:

```
PFUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({...})
```

If you want user a follow user b, you can create a follow class which would be more efficient in the future.

```
let follow = PFObject(className:"MYAPPFollow")
follow["fromUser"] = userA
follow["toUser"]   = userB
follow.save // remember to save your newly created item
```

Comment: I already got that by myself, but thanks :) My question was more about the friends request. I don't want to make it possible just to follow someone, but more like: UserA wants to be friends with UserB so he clicks follow, but before he can really follow him, UserB has to confirm that they are friends.